# formulating a mysqli query that lists out groups that has a separate table for whether user has access to view group

Tags: php, mysqli

I know how to do this with multiple queries; however, I'm asking here to better my knowledge to see if this can be done within 1 query.

```
<select name="group-select" class="group-select">';
$groupslist = $con->query("SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY sort_order ASC");
while($group = $groupslist->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<option value="'. $group['id'] .'" ';
if ($viewGroup == $group['id']) { echo 'selected'; }
echo '>'. $group['name'] .'</option>';
}

echo '</select>
```

Right now, the above is my query to call a groups list.  This will create a new drop down option for each group.

---

Now, I'm currently creating the ability to add users who have access to view each group.  If the user has access to view the group, then I want the group to show up in the drop down list.  If they don't, I don't want it to appear.  So, I created a separate table (groupaccess) that has 3 columns (AI id, group, user) where the group id and user id are added whenever a user is added to the group.  This will allow the user to view the group.

Heres a catch:  Inside the users table, there is a column called 'viewall' where if this = 1, the user has the ability to view all groups and they don't have to be listed inside group access table. This is set up so admin's don't have to be manually added to each group that is created.

I realize I can create multiple queries and while loops within the current while loop listed above searching for the logged in user and group being pulled in first while loop; however, is it possible to just add to the current query.  I'm just trying to create less queries, especially since the groups list may get kinda long.

```
My goal: Create 1 to 2 queries (preferably 1) that accomplishes...
  - Builds a list of groups from the `groups` table where...
       a) users who have groups.viewall set to 1 can view all groups
       b) users who have been added to view group in groupaccess table.
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.  Thank you in advance for your help.  I'm trying to better my knowledge of creating queries while attempting this.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$groupslist = $con->query("select groups.id, groups.name from groups, groupaccess, users where users.id = {userid} AND ( users.viewall = 1 OR ( {userid} = groupaccess.user AND groups.id = groupaccess.group ) ) GROUP BY groups.id ORDER BY groups.sort_order ASC");